# When building my JavaScript project with Webpack I cannot access my code from the console

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm just starting out with Webpack (2.2.1 at the time of posting) and have been so far really pleased with the results. However this morning I have started to build a new project using my Webpack setup and I have noticed that while all of the JS that I write is being built and runs fine in the browser, I cannot seem to access any of the code I have written in the console.

As the simplest example, in my index.js I might have the following:

`const thing = "Why can't you see me?!";`

If I open the built page in my browser (Chrome 57.0.2987.110) and open the console, typing 'thing' gives me the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: thing is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1`

I was wondering if it might be something to do with strict mode that is being enforced by Babel, but if it is I'm not sure how to bypass that.

If it's of any relevance, here is my webpack.config - if there are any glaring errors with this, regardless of whether they are related to this issue, I would welcome the feedback, as I'm still wrapping my head around Webpack.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bundle: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/'),
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
                exclude: '/node_modules/'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']  
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        port: 3500
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: ('src/index.html')
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({}),
    ]
};
```

Comment: maybe packing it, build it inside an anonymous function, to make it public try with `window.thing = thing;` in your code to debug it, when its all OK, remove it

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but basically you cannot access `vars` from your code files in browser console, unless you bind them to global object (window)

Comment: Thanks both - I wasn't fully aware that webpack was modularising everything, which is almost certainly what the problem is. I am used to being able to test functionality of my programs by firing off functions in the console. I may try to bind to global, or I may try a different method of development!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will open bundle.js file, you will see what your code wrapped by Webpack modules function. So their scope is limited by that function and can't be accessed from global scope.

1. You can assign this variable to window object, if you really need that.
2. You can create a separate file with const variables and export them.Then import or require it somewhere you need it.
3. If you need to make libraries as a global variable take a look there https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html

Comment: Ah, ok this makes sense! I am used to being able to trigger functions from the console to test small bits of functionality - perhaps what I actually need to do is stop doing this and come up with a new system!

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to look into [source maps](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#source-maps). The browser is running your compiled code so the source map needs to point back to your source code. There are several [devtool](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) options and there are tradeoffs between compilation speed and accuracy. I suggest `cheap-eval-source-map` for normal dev and `eval-source-map` if you need more accurate debugging.

You can drop `debugger` and `console.log()` statements into your source and debug in the browser as usual. You will not be able to set breakpoints in the browser console because there is no way to trace that breakpoint back to the original line.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I will look into getting some sourcemaps into my code - this seems like a good practice regardless.